# Explaining a regression analysis table

Tags: regression

I need some assistance in explaining a regression analysis table. Can you help me please?
This table is from an article. I have to interpret  the table.

[image]

Comment: It appears that `B` is the result of the statistical analyses, and the 95% confidence intervals of `B` are also provided. `**` are included next to the statistically significant results. Can you link us to the article, or at least include the table legend? I cannot accurately explain/interpret the table without it, since I do not know what `B` stands for. It would also be very helpful if you let us know what we need to specifically interpret and explain about the article? i.e. a specific question, as opposed to a general one. I don't know if you want an explanation of which results are statist

Answer (score -2):

Assuming this is the result from a linear regression. The formula for a linear regression is

$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \cdots + \beta_px_p + \epsilon$$

and the estimated equation is:

$$\hat{y} = \hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1x_1 + \hat\beta_2x_2 + \cdots + \hat\beta_px_p$$

In your table, $B$ represents the estimate of the $\beta$'s in the above equation ($\hat\beta_i$). and the $95\% CI$ is the $95\%$ confidence interval range which represents the variability of the estimate of your $\beta$ parameters.